# Called componentDidMount twice

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a small react app. In App.js I have layout **Sidenav** and **Content** area. The side nav is shown on some page and hid from others. When I go to some components with sidenav, sidenav flag is set by redux and render the component again, in the **componentDidMount** I have api call, and it is executed twice.

```js
class App extends Component {

  renderSidebar = () => {
    const {showNav} = this.props;
    return showNav ? (
            <TwoColumns>
                <Sidenav/>
            </TwoColumns>) : null;
  };

  render() {
    const {showNav} = this.props;
    const Column = showNav ? TenColumns : FullColumn;

    return (
      <Row spacing={0}>
           {this.renderSidebar()}
           <Column>
               <Route exact path="/measurements/:id/:token/:locale/measure"
                                                component={MeasurementPage}/>
           </Column>
      </Row>
    )
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    showNav: state.sidenav.showNav
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

I tried to use **shouldComponentUpdate** to prevent the second API call

```js
class MeasurementPage extends Component { 
  constructor(props) {
    // This update the redux "showNav" flag and re-render the component
    props.toggleSidenav(false);
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return !nextProps.showNav === this.props.showNav;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // This is executed twice and made 2 api calls
    this.props.getMeasurement(params);
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>Some content here</h1>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    showNav: state.sidenav.showNav
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MeasurementPage);
```

Did someone struggle from this state update and how manage to solve it?

Comment: probably you can solve the issue by adding `props.toggleSidenav(false);` in `componentDidMount()` insted of `constructor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `props.toggleSidenav(false)` might cause side effect to your component lifecycle. We use to do this kind of stuff inside `componentWillMount` and it has been depreciated/removed for a reason :). I will suggest you move it inside `componentDidMount`

```
class MeasurementPage extends Component { 
  constructor(props) {
    // This update the redux "showNav" flag and re-render the component
   // props.toggleSidenav(false); // remove this
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return nextProps.showNav !== this.props.showNav;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if(this.props.showNav){ //the if check might not necessary 
      this.props.toggleSidenav(false);
      this.props.getMeasurement(params);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>Some content here</h1>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I fixed it with similar solution :)

Comment: @IvanAbadzhiev, my pleasure, happy to learn by your side, please do mark it as answer if it is

Answer (score 1):

The comparison should be

```
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return !(nextProps.showNav === this.props.showNav)
  }
```

The problem is that `!nextProps.showNav` negate `showNav` value instead of negating the role expression value, and that is why you need an isolation operator.

Comment: This is not the issue: why is `componentDidMount` fire twice?

Comment: Because the parent triggered a re render

Answer (score 0):

It's No call twice anymore.

```js
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.first) return; this.first = true;
    this.props.getMeasurement(params);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).